# Where do I save my own custom rules in Karabiner.json?

Tags: keyboard, customization, karabiner

I have written a custom complex rule for Karabiner Elements. I do not know if I should edit directly the `karabiner/karabiner.json` config file, so I was wondering if I could just save my custom rule inside `karabiner/assets/`, where the other modifications I downloaded (from [Karabiner-Elements complex_modifications rules](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org)) are stored. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you save it in `karabiner/assets/my_complex_rule.json` it will work.